# TypeError: Cannot read property 'formData' of null in application2.js

Tags: javascript, shopify

I see this error in the console, sometimes more than once.

I've tried removing scripts from the page one by one but can't seem to eliminate it.

Appreciate any troubleshooting advice!

```
application2.js?v=1586364314459:22 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'formData' of null

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'formData' of null
    at t.value (application2.js?v=1586364314459:22)
    at t.value (application2.js?v=1586364314459:22)
    at new e (application2.js?v=1586364314459:25)
    at Object.r [as callback] (application2.js?v=1586364314459:35)
    at application2.js?v=1586364314459:31
    at n (application2.js?v=1586364314459:15)
    at application2.js?v=1586364314459:15
    at o (application2.js?v=1586364314459:15)
    at Object.664420680308.7518 (application2.js?v=1586364314459:15)
    at e._handleResponse (application2.js?v=1586364314459:31)
value @ application2.js?v=1586364314459:22
value @ application2.js?v=1586364314459:22
e @ application2.js?v=1586364314459:25
r @ application2.js?v=1586364314459:35
(anonymous) @ application2.js?v=1586364314459:31
n @ application2.js?v=1586364314459:15
(anonymous) @ application2.js?v=1586364314459:15
o @ application2.js?v=1586364314459:15
(anonymous) @ application2.js?v=1586364314459:15
e._handleResponse @ application2.js?v=1586364314459:31
e._dispatch @ application2.js?v=1586364314459:31
(anonymous) @ application2.js?v=1586364314459:31
e._handleMessage @ application2.js?v=1586364314459:31
(anonymous) @ application2.js?v=1586364314459:31
```

Comment: It's impossible to help you with the details provided without knowing what's in your application.js and on the web page (HTML). Provide at least a link to your website and minimal reproducible example

Comment: @Vladimor The site is [link]https://www.fisherwallace.com. Thanks for your help!

Comment: This script belongs to **Olark** app, not to your theme.

Comment: Thanks for that info.